# Tab in org-mode table generates "Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size."

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Pressing `TAB` in an org-mode table (existing, or trying to create a new one) results in an error: 
"Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size."

Debug provides the following:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size")
  beginning-of-line(1)
  org-at-table-p(any)
  org-at-table\.el-p()
  org-element-table-parser(3858 (380))
  org-element--current-element(3858 element nil nil)
  byte-code("`\212\306\307 \211\310   P\311 \210,`)\312\211\211\211\211\211\211*+,-./\306\307 \211\310   P\313 \203Teb\210\314 \210m\204L\315 /V\203\205\316\317\312\"\210\202\205\320 \210\312y\210\314 \210m\204i\315 /V\203\205\316\317\321\312x\210\322 \2100\204~\323d\306\"\202\203\323d\306\"C\"\210,\322 \210\324.\325,*$\211@-\326\f12\211;\203\263\327\31221$\202\304A\330A@21#\240\210+\2100\203\322+B+\3312;\203\351\332\3332#\202\361\334A@2\"*\2113/W\204\f3/U\2053.U?\2053b)\204\211-4>\204.\316\3170\203'+\202)\"\210\202\211\3352;\203E\332\3332#\202M\334A@2\"*\3362;\203e\332\3332#\202m\334A@2\"*5\2116\203\2745\203\2746/V\204\2745/W\204\2746/U\203\232-\337>\204\2745/U\203\317-\340>\204\274-\341>\203\3175b\210n\204\274m\204\317\316\3170\203\310+\202\312\"\210\202@\342-\343\"\203\344,\3452;\203\364\332\3332#\202\374\334A@2\"**\2028\342-\344\"\203\312,\2028\342-\346\"\203!\347,\312*\2028\342-\350\"\2032\351,\312*\2028\312\211,*5.6b\210*\202\211" [org-called-with-limited-levels org-outline-regexp outline-regexp org-outline-regexp-bol parent prevs t org-get-limited-outline-regexp "^" outline-next-heading nil org-before-first-heading-p org-skip-whitespace line-beginning-position throw exit org-back-to-heading " 
    \n" beginning-of-line org-element-headline-parser org-element--current-element element :parent org-add-props plist-put :end get-text-property 0 plist-get :contents-begin :contents-end (plain-list table) (center-block drawer dynamic-block inlinetask property-drawer quote-block special-block) (item plain-list) eql plain-list item :structure property-drawer node-property table table-row struct trail special-flag type end origin keep-trail value ...] 10)
  org-element-at-point()
  org-table-begin(any)
  org-at-table\.el-p()
  org-element-table-parser(3858 (380))
  org-element--current-element(3858 element nil nil)
  byte-code("`\212\306\307 \211\310   P\311 \210,`)\312\211\211\211\211\211\211*+,-./\306\307 \211\310   P\313 \203Teb\210\314 \210m\204L\315 /V\203\205\316\317\312\"\210\202\205\320 \210\312y\210\314 \210m\204i\315 /V\203\205\316\317\321\312x\210\322 \2100\204~\323d\306\"\202\203\323d\306\"C\"\210,\322 \210\324.\325,*$\211@-\326\f12\211;\203\263\327\31221$\202\304A\330A@21#\240\210+\2100\203\322+B+\3312;\203\351\332\3332#\202\361\334A@2\"*\2113/W\204\f3/U\2053.U?\2053b)\204\211-4>\204.\316\3170\203'+\202)\"\210\202\211\3352;\203E\332\3332#\202M\334A@2\"*\3362;\203e\332\3332#\202m\334A@2\"*5\2116\203\2745\203\2746/V\204\2745/W\204\2746/U\203\232-\337>\204\2745/U\203\317-\340>\204\274-\341>\203\3175b\210n\204\274m\204\317\316\3170\203\310+\202\312\"\210\202@\342-\343\"\203\344,\3452;\203\364\332\3332#\202\374\334A@2\"**\2028\342-\344\"\203\312,\2028\342-\346\"\203!\347,\312*\2028\342-\350\"\2032\351,\312*\2028\312\211,*5.6b\210*\202\211" [org-called-with-limited-levels org-outline-regexp outline-regexp org-outline-regexp-bol parent prevs t org-get-limited-outline-regexp "^" outline-next-heading nil org-before-first-heading-p org-skip-whitespace line-beginning-position throw exit org-back-to-heading "
```

. . . (repeating) . . .

```
\n" beginning-of-line org-element-headline-parser org-element--current-element element :parent org-add-props plist-put :end get-text-property 0 plist-get :contents-begin :contents-end (plain-list table) (center-block drawer dynamic-block inlinetask property-drawer quote-block special-block) (item plain-list) eql plain-list item :structure property-drawer node-property table table-row struct trail special-flag type end origin keep-trail value ...] 10)
      org-element-at-point()
      org-table-begin(any)
      org-at-table\.el-p()
      org-element-table-parser(3858 (380))
      org-element--current-element(3858 element nil nil)
      byte-code("`\212\306\307 \211\310   P\311 \210,`)\312\211\211\211\211\211\211*+,-./\306\307 \211\310   P\313 \203Teb\210\314 \210m\204L\315 /V\203\205\316\317\312\"\210\202\205\320 \210\312y\210\314 \210m\204i\315 /V\203\205\316\317\321\312x\210\322 \2100\204~\323d\306\"\202\203\323d\306\"C\"\210,\322 \210\324.\325,*$\211@-\326\f12\211;\203\263\327\31221$\202\304A\330A@21#\240\210+\2100\203\322+B+\3312;\203\351\332\3332#\202\361\334A@2\"*\2113/W\204\f3/U\2053.U?\2053b)\204\211-4>\204.\316\3170\203'+\202)\"\210\202\211\3352;\203E\332\3332#\202M\334A@2\"*\3362;\203e\332\3332#\202m\334A@2\"*5\2116\203\2745\203\2746/V\204\2745/W\204\2746/U\203\232-\337>\204\2745/U\203\317-\340>\204\274-\341>\203\3175b\210n\204\274m\204\317\316\3170\203\310+\202\312\"\210\202@\342-\343\"\203\344,\3452;\203\364\332\3332#\202\374\334A@2\"**\2028\342-\344\"\203\312,\2028\342-\346\"\203!\347,\312*\2028\342-\350\"\2032\351,\312*\2028\312\211,*5.6b\210*\202\211" [org-called-with-limited-levels org-outline-regexp outline-regexp org-outline-regexp-bol parent prevs t org-get-limited-outline-regexp "^" outline-next-heading nil org-before-first-heading-p org-skip-whitespace line-beginning-position throw exit org-back-to-heading " 
        \n" beginning-of-line org-element-headline-parser org-element--current-element element :parent org-add-props plist-put :end get-text-property 0 plist-get :contents-begin :contents-end (plain-list table) (center-block drawer dynamic-block inlinetask property-drawer quote-block special-block) (item plain-list) eql plain-list item :structure property-drawer node-property table table-row struct trail special-flag type end origin keep-trail value ...] 10)
      org-element-at-point()
      org-table-begin(any)
      org-at-table\.el-p()
      org-cycle(nil)
      call-interactively(org-cycle nil nil)
      command-execute(org-cycle)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I'm pretty lost at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remembered that I added `calfw-org` to the init file yesterday night.

Opened the init file and saw that I had `(require 'calfw-org)` before `(require 'org-install)`. I switched the order and everything seems to work now.

I have no idea why this is the case, and why it was creating an error with tables, but am guessing it has to do with the order of how emacs loads packages from the init file.